# Javascript - Alternative to lzw compression for Database entry

Tags: javascript, mysql, compression, lzw

I have strings (about 1-5Kb) of the form:

FF,A3V,X7Y,aA4,....

lzw compresses these really nicely, but includes Turkish characters. These are then submitted to a MySQL database.

Sometimes MySQL can 'play-up' and not submit these properly, putting question marks '?' in place of the Turkish characters. They can do this even when you have your text areas properly defined. Exporting and reimporting the table can sort this out. This is fine for my test database, but not something I am happy with when this goes live.

Consequently I am looking for an alternative to lzw, which will compress but only using normal letters/numbers etc.

Does anyone know of a PUBLIC DOMAIN compression method that avoid Turkish Characters (and any other non-standard characters)? Can anyone point me to some code in javascript (or c++ or c# which I can convert)?

Comment: And how did you determine MySQL puts question marks there, and that it's not your program that you use to view MySQL data who screws up? Are you saving the data in the data type that has no charset associated (varbinary, binary)? Why would you alter the compression algorithm and not fix the charset problems that you obviously have?

Comment: try base64 encoding the (compressed) strings

Comment: Mjh - I have tested each stage. Just prior to submission to the database everything is fine. Retrieving it immediately afterwards you get the same ?-filled string as being displayed in wamp. I am saving in the correct data type, as I have done this for another program which works fine. This seems to be a known issue with turkish char. The solution (known by others on here) to export and re-import does seem to solve the issue. You do not want to be doing the latter in a live situation.

Comment: Nikos M - thanks for the reply. I am looking it up now. I will let you know how I get on.

Comment: So, **which** program are you using to **view** the data and are you using the *appropriate data type* in MySQL to save the data? You need to use the column that doesn't store the charset information - `varbinary` or `binary`. Then you save the binary lzw output. When you pull it out, it's still binary, still no charset info. You uncompress the data and apply the charset and you can view the textual info you had saved. That's how it's done.

Comment: Mjh - I am now confused. I found out about the lzw compression on here where it suggested the output was a string. (It is hard to tell in js.) Consequently I was putting the data into the MySQL table in a 'TEXT' entry. In that case I want to compress my STRING into another STRING. How is this done. (There are reasons why I want the compressed data to be in string form.)

Comment: Strings are just sequences of bytes. They are displayed based on the character set - it acts as a symbol table for bytes. Whether you compress a string or not, what's important which character set has been applied to it. Depending on the charset, you'll get different letters, numbers etc. LZW operates on bytes, it has no notion of character set. That means if you want to keep the input and output in sync, you cannot apply charset to it at any point. Text, varchar and char columns are applying the charset to bytes. That's your problem source.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you are saying I should have a different field rather than a TEXT field in my wamp database as that is doing some form of charset conversion. So what do I use?

Comment: `blob` is equivalent to `text`, `binary` is equivalent to `char`, `varbinary` is equivalent to `varchar`, but they omit the charset info. Use any of them, depending on your storage size needs.

Comment: Thanks Mjh - you have answered my question perfectly. I completely understand now. Everything is working fine. I have marked the answer below (which expanded on what you said) with the tick, but if you write an answer yourself I will tick that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand a bit on what's been said in the comments... Storing strings of bytes, such as the output from a compression algorithm typically contains, in a `VARCHAR` or `CHAR` or `TEXT` column **is not valid usage.**

These column types are not for byte strings, they are for strings of *valid characters* only.  Not every string of bytes contains valid strings of characters in any given character set... and MySQL isn't going to allow invalid characters (which, for some character sets, the correlation between "character" and "byte" isn't 1:1).

In the good ol' days™, the two were interchangeable but this is not the case any more (and hasn't been, to one degree or another, for a while).

If your column type, instead, were `BINARY` or  `VARBINARY` or `BLOB`, the issue should disappear, because those data types are for binary data.

Comment: Thanks Michael. This is the answer. And thanks to Mjh in the comments to my question who also helped considerably.